# why does xmllint give schemas parser error?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing, xmllint

The `shiporder.xml` comes from w3schools; schema validation fails as:

```
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ ls
shiporder.xml
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ trang shiporder.xml shiporder.xsd
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ ls
shiporder.xml  shiporder.xsd  xsi.xsd
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ cat xsi.xsd 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="shiporder.xsd"/>
  <xs:attribute name="noNamespaceSchemaLocation" type="xs:NCName"/>
</xs:schema>
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ cat shiporder.xsd 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="xsi.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="shiporder">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="orderperson"/>
        <xs:element ref="shipto"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="item"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="orderid" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute ref="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="shipto">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="name"/>
        <xs:element ref="address"/>
        <xs:element ref="city"/>
        <xs:element ref="country"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="country" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="item">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="title"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="note"/>
        <xs:element ref="quantity"/>
        <xs:element ref="price"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
</xs:schema>
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ xmllint --noout --schema shiporder.xsd shiporder.xml
xsi.xsd:4: element attribute: Schemas parser error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}attribute': The target namespace must not match 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'.
WXS schema shiporder.xsd failed to compile
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ cat shiporder.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<shiporder orderid="889923"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>
</shiporder> 


thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$
```

Shouldn't `xmllint` be able to verify the [document](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_example.asp) as valid seeing as how the `xsd` was generated through `trang`?

Comment: What is the contents of your shiporder.xsd file?  Because what the error is showing is the XML payload example, and the error is indicating that the XSD does does not have the namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

Comment: that was the solution, @Dijkgraaf    thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I tooks out lines 2 and 12 which referenced "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" so that it now validates:

```
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ xmllint --noout --schema shiporder.xsd shiporder.xml
shiporder.xml validates
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ ls
shiporder.xml  shiporder.xsd  xsi.xsd
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ cat xsi.xsd 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="shiporder.xsd"/>
  <xs:attribute name="noNamespaceSchemaLocation" type="xs:NCName"/>
</xs:schema>
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$ cat shiporder.xsd 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xs:element name="shiporder">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="orderperson"/>
        <xs:element ref="shipto"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="item"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="orderid" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="shipto">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="name"/>
        <xs:element ref="address"/>
        <xs:element ref="city"/>
        <xs:element ref="country"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="country" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="item">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="title"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="note"/>
        <xs:element ref="quantity"/>
        <xs:element ref="price"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
</xs:schema>
thufir@dur:~/xml/ship$
```

But why?  And, could I not have generated the `xsd` so that either there was no such reference, or that the reference was, well, referenced **correctly**?